# Web design - Fixing length of To, CC and BCC text fields

Tags: html, web, html-email

I am designing a web page to accept email addresses to be used for user notification. In the process trying fix the length of to, cc and bcc fields.

As per RFC 2821/3696 max length of an email address can go up to 256 characters, and maximum number of email addresses an email exchange can be up to 125. That says the max length of the field coming around (256*125) ~ 35000 characters.

Providing such a text box is practically not convincing/viable.

Would like to know if there are any standards/best practices to fix number of characters to, cc, bcc field should allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These RFCs are about the size for storing such addresses, not for displaying a UI widget in which to enter that data. Most text inputs allow one to add text that is longer than the input field; if you use a standard `<input type="email">` element, the `width` that you specify only limits the space that it takes up, not the number of characters that can be entered; if a user types more characters than the width, then they end up in a scenario where they have to scroll within the element, but they can still enter more characters than the specified amount.

My advice would be to not fix the number of allowable characters at all (beyond what you need to prevent abuse / protect your service), but to select a widget size that looks reasonable (usually in the vicinity of 25-30 characters wide, though if this is the "To" line, then unless you have a different way of doing this, you should also support a list of email addresses, which would need to be longer).

Comment: Make sense. Thanks!!!